# Beautiful Soup Object

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i'm having an issue with beautiful soup. Specifically with the .find method. Is there a way that i can have it match broad instead of exact match? Right now it works only if First Last is found.

```
soup.find("a", string="First Last").get('href')
```

Id want it to find any one of the combination of these two words with or without capital letters. so it would find

```
First
first
Last first
last last
something something last
etc..
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you provide a small snippet of the page you are working on to execute some tests upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [Kinds of filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters) explains all of the many options in depth. (Make sure to continue on through at least the `find_all()`, `name`, and keyword arguments sections after this one; that's where you'll find the best examples.)

The one you're using does exact matches only:

> The simplest filter is a string. Pass a string to a search method and Beautiful Soup will perform a match against that exact string.

---

But you can use, e.g., [a regex](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) instead:

> If you pass in a regular expression object, Beautiful Soup will filter against that regular expression using its search() method.

```
soup.find("a", string=re.compile(r'(?i)(first|last)'))
```

---

… or [a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

> If none of the other matches work for you, define a function that takes an element as its only argument. The function should return True if the argument matches, and False otherwise.

```
def matches_firstlast(s):
    lower = s.casefold()
    return 'first' in lower or 'last' in lower
soup.find("a", string=matches_firstlast)
```

You could also write a function that takes the whole tag, instead of just its `string`, which could be more resilient against errors caused by unexpected tags, if that's an issue.

---

You haven't specified very clearly what the exact rule that you want is, or given us a complete example to test against, so I can't promise that the regex or the function actually do exactly what you want. Here's an example:

```
>>> h =  '<a>first</a> <a>last first</a> <a>something something last</a> <a>larst fist</a> <p>First Last</p>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'lxml')
>>> soup.find_all("a", string=re.compile(r'(?i)(first|last)'))
[<a>first</a>, <a>last first</a>, <a>something something last</a>]
>>> soup.find_all("a", string=matches_firstlast)
[<a>first</a>, <a>last first</a>, <a>something something last</a>]
```

Hopefully this—and the docs—are enough to code up whatever you need.